# CATIA-CAA CATNavigBox Resize

Tags: treeview, catia, caa

Is it possible to change the size of the treeview window after it has been visualized?

My code looks like this:

```
    _p2DNavViewer = NULL;       
    _p2DNavViewer = new CATNavigation2DViewer(this, "", CATDlgFraNoTitle | CATDlgWndNoDecoration |CATDlgWndChildMDI |CATDlgFraNoFrame, _width, _height);


    _pNavigBox = new CATNavigBox(this, "", NULL, Indented, "CATINavigateObject_ForCAA2", 0, 0, _p2DNavViewer);
```

*this* is the surrounding `CATDlgContainer`.

I can't find anything that would indicate that it's possible, but CATIA is doing it so there has to be a way.
I'm using CAAV5 R16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm catching a Resizecallback from the `CATDlgContainer`

```
AddAnalyseNotificationCB(this,this->GetResizeNotification(), 
    (CATCommandMethod)&PROTrvTreeView::OnContainerResizeNotification,
    NULL);
```

The catching method looks like this:

```
void PROTrvTreeView::OnContainerResizeNotification(CATCommand* cmd, 
                  CATNotification* evt, CATCommandClientData data) {
    DRECT * pRect = new DRECT();
    GetRectDimensions(pRect);
    if (pRect != NULL) {
        _p2DNavViewer->SetRectDimensions(pRect->x,pRect->y, pRect->dy, pRect->dx);
    }
    delete pRect;
    pRect = NULL;
}
```

So it was `_p2DNavViewer->SetRectDimensions` all along.